# implementing a horizontal bar graph in mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am relatively new to .Net MVC 3 (using Razor syntax) and I am stuck with a small requirement.

I have a dropdpwn with two string values (Conservative, Moderate) in it. Each string value is associated with its corresponding 'Min', 'Max' and 'Avg' values coming from a Model. Now I have to show a horizontal bar graph with x values (Conservative, Moderate) and y values (0% to 100%). Now whenever I select a dropdown value, the graph should be updated in such a way that, it should color the area between 'Min' and 'Max' values on y-axis for Conservative, Moderate and also display the Min(Eg; 10%) and Max(Eg; 50%) values on the top of it for the selected dropdown value. 
Also, the corresponding 'Average' value should be displayed as a pointer on the graph for the Conservative, Moderate (x values) when a checkbox (below the dropdown)is checked.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You have several ways of doing this (even more than just this)
1. Do it the "MVC" way and use jQuery : )  Everyone is doing it : )
Use one of the jQuery graph plugins:
http://workshop.rs/jqbargraph/

1. make an ajax call an aspx page where you use a web forms chart control.
2. Use a partial view as your graph. Put that in an ajax.beginform. Selecting the dropdown values causes a postback to your controller method which packages your data - could be an inline image (you can fully encode the bytes to an image in html, thereby not requiring a separate call to load the image)
   simply values that get turned into an html div that mimics a bar chart.

personally - I would choose #1

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But, as I said I have a very little idea of how to implement your solution. So, can you please provide me a sample solution file for the MVC way (razor engine). I apologize for my ignorance.

Comment: But, as I said I have a very little idea of how to implement your solution. So, can you please provide me a sample solution file for my problem in the MVC way (razor engine). I apologize for my ignorance.